# Show that $\operatorname{Alt}(4)$ has no subgroup of order $6,$ help understanding proof.

Tags: abstract-algebra

I need help breaking down this proof:

> Show that $\operatorname{Alt}(4)$ has no subgroup of order $6.$

Proof. Suppose to the contrary that $\operatorname{Alt}(4)$ has a subgroup $H$ of order $6.$ Then $[\operatorname{Alt}(4):H] = |\operatorname{Alt}(4)|/|H| = 2.$ It follows that $H \lhd \operatorname{Alt}(4),$ and so the quotient group $\operatorname{Alt}(4)/H$ is a group of order $2.$ Suppose that $a \in \operatorname{Alt}(4)$ and that $o(a) = 3$ (order of element). Then $a^3 = 1$. This means that $(aH)^3 = a^3 H = H.$ Thus $aH \in \operatorname{Alt}(4)/H$ with $o(aH) = 3.$

However $\operatorname{Alt}(4)/H$ contains no elements of order $3.$  Hence $o(aH) = 1,$ so that $aH = H \Rightarrow a \in H.$ Since $\operatorname{Alt}(4)$ contains $\frac{4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2}{3} = 8$ elements of order $3,$ it can't possibly be the case that $H$ contains all these elements since it was earlier assumed that $|H| = 6.$ This is a contradiction. $\text{ } \Box$

> However $\operatorname{Alt}(4)/H$ contains no elements of order $3.$

How do we know this?

> Hence $o(aH) = 1$

Why does the order of $aH$ automatically get reduced to $1$ when the order can't be $3$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Because we know that this is a group of order 2
2. Because we have just shows that the order is a divisor of 3 and is $\ne3$

Comment: Oh right, because the order of an element needs to divide the order of the group. I feel silly.